# Запись в БД при селекте

Tags: php

На странице пользователю нужно выбрать либо права, либо водительское удостоверение.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<div class="v_radio">
                            <input name="r" id="r1" type="radio">
                            <label for="r1">
                                <img class="v-r1" src="img/icons/v-id.png">
                                <span>Passport</span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="r" id="r2" type="radio">
                            <label for="r2">
                                <img class="v-r2" src="img/icons/v-passport--green.png">
                                <span>Driver license</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии next, в БД записало значение 0 или 1, в зависимости от выбора

Comment: попробуйте ajax. А лучше приложите код который есть (что сделано и что не работает)

Comment: @Nilsan кода к сожалению нет, н езнаю в каком направлении копать

Comment: mysql + php + ajax в этом направлении. По клику js отправляет в php, а php записывает\обновляет значение в бд

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
   <div class="v_radio">
    <input name="r" id="r1" type="radio">
    <label for="r1">
        <img class="v-r1" src="img/icons/v-id.png">
        <span>Passport</span>
    </label>
    <input name="r" id="r2" type="radio">
    <label for="r2">
        <img class="v-r2" src="img/icons/v-passport--green.png">
        <span>Driver license</span>
    </label>
</div>
<button type="submit">next</button>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST["r1"])) {
    $filed = 1;
}
if (isset($_POST["r2"])) {
    $filed = 0;
}
?>
```

где $filed - поле в бд